# How to iterate through matching IDs from two PS objects to output items that match?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My goal is to find all stale Azure Pipelines, based on the queueTime of the associated pipeline runs, and output them to a report.  My logic is to pull back all pipeline IDs and names, then pull back all runs newer than a certain date.  I have a list of pipeline names and IDs, and a list of run names (buildNumber) and the run's associated pipeline ID of that run (definition.id).  If I iterate through the objects and their IDs, I should be able to eliminate pipelines with runs newer than a certain date and keep the rest as a list of stale pipelines.  I've been tasked with using foreach to iterate though the list, but I'm struggline to figure out how to use foreach and a good way to keep/ouptut the stale pipelines - maybe in a new object.
Any assistance with foreach iteration and output would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, J

```
    #Parameters
    [int32]$days = 10  #I have days because my sample set doesn't include results older than months yet - until we add classic
    [int32]$months = 1
    [string]$org = 'contoso'
    [string]$project = 'daedalus'
    [dateTime]$daysBack = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(((-$days))) -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"
    [dateTime]$monthsBack = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths((-$months)) -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"
    #Auth
    $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = 'fdsalkjslkfdjsflkjafjldsj'
```

```
    #Find all pipelines - just YAML so far - not yet classic
    [string]$pipelinesQuery = "[].{ PipelineName:name,PipelineURL:url,PipelineID:id }"
    $pipelinesList = (az pipelines list --organization "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" --project $project --query $pipelinesQuery --output json | ConvertFrom-Json)
    $allPipes = $pipelinesList | Where-Object -Property PipelineID -NE $null | Select-Object PipelineName, PipelineID   
    $allPipes
```

```
    #Find all runs newer than certain date
    [string]$runsQuery = "[].{ RunPipeName:definition.name,RunName:buildNumber,RunQueueTime:queueTime,RunID:id,RunPipeID:definition.id }"
    $runsList = (az pipelines runs list --organization "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" --project $project --query $runsQuery --output json | ConvertFrom-Json)
    $freshRuns = $runsList | Where-Object -Property RunQueueTime -gt $daysBack | Select-Object RunName, RunPipeID
    $freshRuns
```

Sample results from current expressions.  Eventually iterating output from the two objects.

```
    PipelineName                                      PipelineID
    ------------                                      ----------
    UseCases                                                  55
    PowerShell Script Deploy                                 108
    EnvironmentPush                                          149
    Accounting                                               150
    Monkeys                                                  151
    Hot Air Balloons                                         152
    
    RunName     RunPipeID
    -------     ---------
    20210810.1         55
    20210810.2         55
    20210813.1        108
    20210814.1        361
    20210813.6        361
    20210813.7        361
```

Comment: So what you'd be interested in outputting here is `"EnvironmentPush", "Accounting", "Monkeys", "Hot Air Balloons"` basically?

Comment: Yes, plus technically the report needs to have the ID of the stale pipelines and the URI/URL of the stale pipeline.  Once I have that information, I’ll output to CSV and share the report for approval to delete the stake pipelines.  Down the road I’ll automate the deletion, create a web based report, put it in an ADO pipeline and allow our SREs to do the process. Thanks!